# Delete the contents of all files in BASH recursively?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I know how to delete the cotents of a file

```
> file.txt
```

But how can I do it recursively from a directory? And only for files with a certain extension

Comment: You may want to try `find directory -type f -name '*.ext' -exec bash -c '> {} ' \;`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin find would not be very effective, maybe better to use `-exec truncate -s  {} +` would be better.